# what does String getname() signifies?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

```
public class AttackName {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    DatacenterBroker broker;
    String fname, lname1, card;

    public DatacenterBroker attack(String path, String fname, String lname) {
        try {


            String filepath = path;
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(filepath);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            System.out.println("attacker doing attack");
            System.out.println("xpath query #1");


            XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            XPath xpath = xpf.newXPath();
            XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//employee[firstname/text()='"+fname+"']/credit_card/text()");

            Object res = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

            NodeList nodes = (NodeList) res;
            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                card = nodes.item(i).getNodeValue();

            }

            XPathFactory xpf1 = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            XPath xpath1 = xpf1.newXPath();
            XPathExpression expr1 = xpath1.compile("//employee[firstname/text()='"+fname+"']/lastname/text()");

            Object res1 = expr1.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

            NodeList nodes1 = (NodeList) res1;
            for (int i = 0; i < nodes1.getLength(); i++) {
                lname1 = nodes1.item(i).getNodeValue();

            }

            System.out.println("attacker doing attack");
            System.out.println("xpath query #2");
            xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            xpath = xpf.newXPath();
            expr = xpath.compile("//employee[firstname/text()='efg' ]/credit_card/text()");

            res = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

            nodes = (NodeList) res;
            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());
            }

            System.out.println("attacker doing attack");

            System.out.println("xpath query #3");
            xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            xpath = xpf.newXPath();
            expr = xpath.compile("//employee[firstname/text()='"+fname+"' and lastname/text()='']/credit_card/text()");

            }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return broker;
    }

    public String getLname(){        
        return lname1;
    }

    public String getCard(){
        return card;
    }
}
```

I am doing xpath injection attack? I have the code with me. I want to understand the code. The rest is fine. but I want to know that what does String `getLname()` and String `getcard()` signifies in the code?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This two methods:

```
public String getLname()
public String getCard()
```

Are giving the possibility to classes of other packages to be able of getting or *reading* attributes `lname` and `card` of your class.

---

Lets explain better. First check this table:

**Access Levels**

```
Modifier    Class   Package Subclass    World
public      Y       Y       Y           Y
protected   Y       Y       Y           N
no modifier Y       Y       N           N
private     Y       N       N           N
```

You have no modifier in:

```
String fname, lname1, card;
```

So this attributes are only visible in your class and others in same package.

This methods are called `getters`, and have brothers, the `setters`. This is a [nice practice](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html): you declare your class fields as private:

```
private String myAttribute;
```

And grand a protected access and modification of your attributes, you can put validation, checks and anythig you want:

```
public String getMyAttribute() {
    // safe return (if null returns "")
    return this.myAttribute == null ? "" : this.myAttribute;
}

public void setMyAttribute(String myAttribute) {
    // validations
    if (myAttribute.startsWith("My") {
       this.myAttribute = myAttribute;
    } else {
       this.myAttribute = "My" + myAttribute;
    }
}
```

Comment: Castila 
are these getters fetching the lname and fname? and is it necessay to have setters in the same class

Comment: check my edit, a) they are not fetching, they make lname and card visible to other members of your project in different package. b) you only have to put `setters` if you want other classes be able to modify your attributes

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that each broker in the system has a specific name and card linked to their user perhaps. I'm not sure what a 'card' is but all the functions do is return a string. I guess the name and card must be set somewhere else in the system and they're used in the attack function at certain points to change what happens to which user. The attack function doesn't make much sense to me seeing as there's three blocks of almost repeated code but don't mind me...

Answer (score 0):

`String getLname()` and `String getCard()` return member variables. In that code snippet, however, they might not be initialised, i.e. if the file does not contain valid data, both return `null`.